# Visualforce-Community: Is it possibe to override the errorpages AND get there a full Exception display including StackTrace?

Tags: visualforce, exception, stacktrace

Working on Communities, but getting only the generic Errorpages is not useful for managing bug-reports.

By default it looks like this:

[image]

I know how to override that here:

[image]

I would like to see as much details as possible, including Line number, Exception type, Stacktrace, etc.

Is it possible in custom VF-error pages to display all that information? I need this even to work for Limit-Exception and especially for them since they are not catchable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found at least these global VF-variables to become handy

```
{!$Site.ErrorMessage} 
{!$Site.OriginalUrl}
{!$Site.ErrorDescription}
{!$User.id}
```

Now I get at least something like this:

[image]

But still the **stacktrace** is missing painfully...